# Reading MSR paraphrase corpus into Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, corpus, csv

I downloaded MSR paraphrase corpus from [MSR](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52398&from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdownloads%2F607d14d9-20cd-47e3-85bc-a2f65cd28042%2Fdefault.aspx) and tried loading it into dataframe, but got the following error:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\MSRParaphraseCorpus\msr_paraphrase_test.txt', sep = '\t' )
```

ERROR:

```
CParserError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-35d992467320> in <module>()
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\MSRParaphraseCorpus\msr_paraphrase_test.txt', sep = '\t' )

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, dialect, compression, doublequote, escapechar, quotechar, quoting, skipinitialspace, lineterminator, header, index_col, names, prefix, skiprows, skipfooter, skip_footer, na_values, na_fvalues, true_values, false_values, delimiter, converters, dtype, usecols, engine, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, na_filter, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, warn_bad_lines, error_bad_lines, keep_default_na, thousands, comment, decimal, parse_dates, keep_date_col, dayfirst, date_parser, memory_map, float_precision, nrows, iterator, chunksize, verbose, encoding, squeeze, mangle_dupe_cols, tupleize_cols, infer_datetime_format, skip_blank_lines)
    472                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    473 
--> 474         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    475 
    476     parser_f.__name__ = name

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    258         return parser
    259 
--> 260     return parser.read()
    261 
    262 _parser_defaults = {

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
    719                 raise ValueError('skip_footer not supported for iteration')
    720 
--> 721         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
    722 
    723         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1168 
   1169         try:
-> 1170             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1171         except StopIteration:
   1172             if nrows is None:

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:7566)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:7806)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\parser.c:8423)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas\parser.c:8297)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas\parser.c:20715)()

CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 34, saw 6
```

So I looked at line 34, and it looks perfectly fine.

```
  fname = r'C:\MSRParaphraseCorpus\msr_paraphrase_test.txt'
    with open(fname, encoding="utf8") as f:
        content = f.readlines()

    content[34]
```

Output:

```
'0\t1268500\t1268733\tAgainst the Japanese currency, the euro was at 135.92/6.04 yen against the late New York level of 136.03/14.\tThe dollar was at 117.85 yen against the Japanese currency, up 0.1 percent.\n'
```

Comment: Line 34 is actually content[33] and the problem with that line is that the last field has a starting quote but no ending one.  You would need to do pd.read_csv(r'C:\MSRParaphraseCorpus\msr_paraphrase_test.txt', sep = '\t', quotechar='') to get the csv reader to ignore quotes.  Not posting as an answer because there are additional problems trying to load the file after fixing that.  The additional problems aren't jumping out at me and the error isn't as clear.   But I'll look a bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the open quotes on line 34 (as mentioned in my comment).   Disable the csv reader's quoting by passing in csv.QUOTE_NONE.  Try:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\MSRParaphraseCorpus\msr_paraphrase_test.txt', sep = '\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```